# Why aren't state and federal prisons forced to allow prison inmates to vote at least in federal elections?

Tags: united-states, law, voting, prison

Someone claimed that current prisoners are allowed to run for federal offices like the House of Representatives and fact checkers said that was true. We are not talking about people released but people *currently* incarcerated.

However, all but two states do not let prisoners vote in prison though most states let people vote post release. If people are theoretically allowed to *run for office*, why isn't there federal law saying prisoners must be able to cast ballots for federal elections?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Because [losing your franchise](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Felony_disenfranchisement_in_the_United_States) is one of the consequences of conviction of (many) crimes in the United States.

Eligibility to run from prison is most likely an oversight in the design of the electoral systems; until you're confronted with the reality of it, who on earth would imagine it to be practicable?

There is an argument for continuing to allow it, however: Presumably voters will be able to tell the difference between someone who has been jailed for actual criminality and malevolence, and someone who has been jailed as political persecution - in which case, they should be empowered to overrule the arresting authority by electing that person to office.

The lack of a Federal law guaranteeing voting rights to prisoners is part of the fractured, federalist system the United States inherited from its inception: voting eligibility, and the administration of elections are handled by state governments, and with only a small number of exceptions the Federal government keeps its hands off. [And those exceptions have recently been curtailed by the Supreme Court](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shelby_County_v._Holder).

Comment: I think it should also be noted that even if someone who is in jail wins it is unlikely that it would get them out of jail in order to serve in the office they got elected to.

Comment: Depends on the office. Federal offices tend to come with immunity to interference by police in carrying out the duties of your office. I could easily see a scenario where the elected was released from prison during the day do go to the chamber and do their job, returning to prison at the end of the work day.

Comment: I am not sure if that also includes getting someone out of jail.

Comment: None of us are sure, it's never been tested. XD

Comment: It's not an oversight; this prevents jailing your opponents to make them ineligible. And if they win, they come out and hold office.

Comment: @WilliamWalkerIII Or staying out for the entire session, as long as the body in question is sitting or in session. I presume most state senates and congresses work like that (based on how the federal system works) - feel free to correct if I am being ignorant.

Comment: @joshua Thank you for repeating part of my answer. I'm guessing it got buried.

Comment: @StianYttervik That's also a very possible outcome. If it were me, I'd argue that having to return to prison every night meant I couldn't do constituent services, etc. - other normal tasks that come with the job.